# CustomActionFilter not getting called for POST/PUT endpoint in web api

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1, action-filter

I need to implement custom action filter so that I could customize the `BadRequest` response to be invoked for the endpoint parameters' model state.

The custom action filter looks like-

```
 using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding;

namespace RestAPI.Extensions
{
    public class ValidateActionParametersAttribute:ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public ValidateActionParametersAttribute()
        {
              //constructor gets called when endpoint is called 
              //with empty body , but not the overridden methods
        }
        public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
        {
            throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
        {
            //check various scenarios
            //like if model is null.
            //like arguments passed in correct syntax or not.
            base.OnActionExecuting(context);
        }
}
```

I then register this filter in Startup.cs, ConfigureServices.

```
  //add action filter
        services.AddScoped<ValidateActionParametersAttribute>();
```

My `POST` action method.

```
//My Controller is inherited from other controller which being base inherits from ControllerBase
[Produces(MediaTypeNames.Application.Json)]
public class AuthController : BaseApiController
{
        [Route("login")]
        [HttpPost]
        [ServiceFilter(typeof(ValidateActionParametersAttribute))]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized)]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status405MethodNotAllowed)]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status503ServiceUnavailable)]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError)]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Login([FromBody]LoginInputModel login)
        {               
            //endpoint logic
        }
}
```

At last , the model that I pass to `Login` endpoint

```
 /// <summary>
/// model to be used as paramter body for login.
/// </summary>
public class LoginInputModel
{      
    [EmailAddress]
    [Required(ErrorMessage ="EmailId is needed")]
    [Display(Description ="Email for login",ResourceType =typeof(string))]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }
   
    [Display(Name = "Remember me?")]
    public bool RememberMe { get; set; }

}
```

I want to return `BadRequest` response with customized structure, but in my case , debugger just doesn't comes to `OnActionExecuted()` method..

> I am trying to invoke the endpoint with empty body or invalid input
> login body..

The action filter does not gets executed, instead `BadRequest` response is returned in some Autogenerated format.

Sample Response that I get-
[image: POST request with empty body]

Can somebody help me resolve this?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you found out about `SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter`? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#default-badrequest-response

Comment: So it's not that your filter doesn't work, ASP.NET Core's filters kick in before yours.